# Android WifiScans inside a background service

Tags: android, service, background, wifi

I am running wifi scans as a service inside an sdk that sits inside another parent app. 
The current behavior is that the parent app should request location permission along with the GPS being enabled and it being in the foreground for the `wifimanager.getScanResults()` to return scanResults.
To bypass the location permission and turning on GPS dependency, the crude hack that I am using is to set the app's targetSDKVersion to 21 or lower.
So, now is there a way to also get the scanResults when the app is in the background and/or killed?